Issue in connecting to snowflake when implementing SchemChange CICD approach
I'm trying to implement the schemachnage cicd approach using github workflows to migrate to different environments (test/prd).
Below is my yaml file code. But it is not working as intended? I checked the schemaChange documentation and followed the same ? can someone help with this. Below is the yml code I was using.
I have the config file under the root directory /cicd/test/schemachange-config.yml
same for prod. And I declared teh password as environment variable. But it is throwing error like authentication issue. I'm sure that my password is correct.
name: Snowflake_CICD
 
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch: 
 
jobs:
  deploy_tst:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: tst
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Set up Python 3.8
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: '3.8'
 
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install schemachange
 
      - name: Deploy to TST
        env:
          SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.SNOWFLAKE_PASS }}
        run: |
          schemachange --config-folder ${{ github.workspace }}/cicd/test
 
  deploy_prd:
    needs: deploy_tst
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: prd
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
 
      - name: Set up Python 3.8
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: '3.8' 
 
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install schemachange
 
      - name: Deploy to PRD
        env:
          SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.SNOWFLAKE_PASS }}
        run: |
          schemachange --config-folder ${{ github.workspace }}/cicd/prod

Kindly help me to correct the code
Error: snowflake.connector.errors.OperationalError: 250001: Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 2 attempt(s).Aborting

Please update your question with the full error message

Hi Nick, please find the error message updated in the question.

And what does the log in snowflake say about your connection? Is it noted at all, blocked, incorrect, or missing?
